# How can I determine where network data is going?

Tags: network, internet, activity-monitor

Activity Monitor always reports several kB or MB being transferred. I do not know where it's going or coming from. How can I find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the most convenient and simple solution is the Network Monitor of [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html).

It monitors all outgoing and incoming network in real time and provides

> fine grained traffic information, combined with powerful yet simple options for analyzing bandwidth, traffic totals, connectivity status and much more.

Network traffic filtered by process (here network time protocol daemon):

[image]

Info for all ntpd traffic:

[image]

Info for one of the ntpd servers:

[image]

You can also filter for hostnames, ports or IP numbers.

---

A single license is ~30 €/$30. Black Friday offer is much cheaper - coupons are available sometimes.

No affiliation with Objective Development here.